# SQLITE STRFTIME adding more than one modifier

Tags: sqlite, strftime

```
1. Use the strftime function with the date 2019-04-01 and display the given date along with the time
2. Use THE strftime function with the date 2019-04-01 and add 2 years to the given date, add 180 minutes to that date

1. SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', '2019-04-01');
2. select strftime('%Y-%m-%d','2019-04-01','+2 years, +180 minutes');
```

I've tried the above two queries for both questions but i'm not getting even i didn't find any more tutorials of STRFTIME

Can anyone sort out this??

Answer (score 1):

The right way is

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', '2019-04-01', '+2 years', '+180 minutes');
```

**+2 years and +180 minutes** must be separate arguments.

You'll find some samples here:
https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: what will be the answer for first question

Comment: @aenugulakarthik If you mean `SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', '2019-04-01');` you need to [edit] the question to show what you're getting, and why that isn't what you want (I get `2019-04-01 00:00` which is exactly what I would expect and fits the question as I understand it).

Comment: @aenugulakarthik you didn't set a Datetime ("2019-04-01 11:12"), just a Date ("2019-04-01"), so you get a "00:00" as result!

Answer (score 1):

I think we are not sure about the format that the time to be printed.
So, we need to apply all possible time formats.

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '2019-04-01');
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S','2019-04-01','+2 years, +180 minutes');
```

This might be the solution to the task.